# Compiled PostgreSQL 9.0.2 on Amazon EC2 has no service or startup script

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql

I built postgresql on EC2 and it is running fine. However, I have been manually controlling it from 'pg_ctl start/stop' as there seems to have been no service configured or evident way to configure the database server to start at boot and stop at shutdown. I have searched and searched and can find nothing. Do I have to make one? If so, how?

Comment: Why don't you use rpms available at http://yum.postgresql.org/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you built PostgreSQL manually, then yes, you'll have to take care of the startup script yourself.
The official RPMs should have one you can copy.

Edit: [initscript from Fedora 13](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=postgresql.init;h=44d032c529d74917c60abe330c5f1b1dc80b7c67;hb=f13)

Comment: Thanks. If anyone has examples, I would appreciate it. I'm not in a position to install the RPM anywhere right now.

Comment: So, unpack the RPM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find one suitable for your OS or make one yourself. Some source packages come with startup scripts for several distributions. You can try this option also.

If you failed with all these options, you can install it with the package manager and get the startup script. It is preferred to this do on another testing machine.